# Replacing empty values with NaN in object/categorical variables

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

So I've searched SO for this and found a bunch of useful threads on how to replace empty values with NaN. However I can't get any of them to work on my DataFrame.

I've used:

```
df.replace('', np.NaN)
df3 = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x == '' else x)
```

and even:

```
df.iloc[:,86:350] = df.iloc[:,86:350].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
```

and the code runs fine without error but when I look in my dataframe i still have b'' values instead of NaN. Any ideas on what I am missing?

I'm sorry for not giving the code to reproduce this as I don't know how to do that as I suspect it's specific to my dataframe which I imported from SPSS and these values were string variables in SPSS if that helps.

Comment: `df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)`?

Comment: `b'' != ''`? Are your `''` values now NaN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your second try:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN if not x else x)
```

To show that both `''` and `b''` will evaluate to `True` in the conditional:

```
l = ['', b'']

for x in l:
    if x:
       print ('Not empty')
    else:
       print ('Empty')

>>> Empty
>>> Empty
```

Sample:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import NaN

df = DataFrame([[1,2,''], ['',b'',3], [4, 5, b'']])
print (df)

# Output
    0    1    2
0   1    2    
1      b''    3
2   4    5  b''

df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: NaN if not x else x)
print (df2)

# Output
    0    1    2
0   1    2  NaN  
1 NaN  NaN    3
2   4    5  NaN
```